# Пакеты NPM и VK

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, npm, qr

Как установить пакет ни по инструкциям в документации VK, ни по инструкциям документации NPM и ни по инструкциям интернета так и не удалось. А пакет очень нужен. Как не пытался, то нарушена цепочка сертификатов, то не нравиться package.json, вообщем куча проблем.

Речь об этом пакете https://vk.com/dev/vk_qr

Возможно ли каким то образом получить пакет в обход NPM?

Есть приложи пример, но толку от него оказалось никакого ( https://vk.com/app6899379 ). Получилось скачать само приложение, оно работает все ок, но вот вытащить из него функции которые отвечают за генерацию из ссылки QR так и не получилось...

*Нужен именно этот пакет из-за того что ни где больше не нашел "красивых" QR.*

Comment: Вам нужны просто исходники пакета?

Comment: Полагаю да.
Главное чтобы работало :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Ищем пакет в реестре](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=vk-qr)
   Выходит, что там их 2, причем тот, что второй, обновляется почаще того, что ищете вы. Но тем не менее, для примера возьмем тот, который просто `vk-qr`. Для второго должно быть все аналогично
2. Переходим на страницу пакета, справа будет ссылка на [репозиторий](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-qr)
3. Дальше есть несколько вариантов развития событий

   1. Заключается в том, что автор пакета директорию `dist` по тем или иным причинам в `.gitignore` не добавил, поэтому в принципе, все, что вам нужно сделать, - это скачать (склонировать) репозиторий, взять интересующий файл из директории `dist` - и, вуа ля, - рабочий код у вас
   2. Можно еще попробовать склонировать репозиторий на локальную машину и запустить `npm i && npm pack`, который должен на выходе выдать вам `.zip` архив с пакетом, абсолютно аналогичным тому, что лежит в реестре

Дальше уже дело за малым, останется только как-то пакет установить. Можно, я думаю, засунуть полученный пакет вручную в `node_modules` (локальный или общий, решайте сами). А можно попробовать связать пакет с помощью `npm link`, но так или иначе вы, вроде бы, лишаетесь возможности обновления.

На крайний случай, если вы последовали моему совету просто вытащить собранный файл из `dist`, то этот файл можете в качестве отдельного самостоятельного скрипта попробовать добавить в ваш проект (как будто бы это и не пакет вовсе, а просто самописный скрипт).

Comment: Но в общем случае, хочу заметить, благоразумнее было бы попытаться починить установку с помощью `npm`. Но тут уже решайте сами, как вам проще и удобнее.

Comment: Получилось все же через npm установить, но теперь при запуске js файла при импорте пишет неизвестный идентификатор после import ( import qr from 'index.js'; ) P.S. index.js находиться в том же каталоге что и js в котором import

Comment: @Demon ну это уже потому что Node в `import`'ы до сих пор не научился. Используйте сборщики или флаги специальные - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import/39436580#39436580